# Elixir case statement

Tags: elixir

I've written a statement as follows:

```
case length(clicks) do
      0 ->
        date_list = []
      1 ->
        date_list = start_date
      _ ->
        date_list = Interval.new(from: start_date, until: end_date) |> Enum.to_list
    end
```

It seems like `date_list` is never set. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm curious what exactly it is you're trying to implement with all the date-related questions recently. 

Comment: I'm building an internal tool to redirect and track traffic, with graphs to show the traffic! The data comes from Postgres, and you need to stick zeros in on the sparse days to actually plot the graphs with JS ;)

Comment: I'm really using the whole thing as an exercise to develop my skills with Elixir. Having done a lot of Python, honestly Elixir is one of the prettiest languages I've ever had the pleasure of using.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While the answer by Denis is technically correct, using [`Kernel.length/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Kernel.html#length/1) is a bad practice in general, since it **traverses the whole list**.

Use direct pattern matching instead:

```
date_list =
  case clicks do
    [] -> []
    [_] -> start_date
    [_ | _] -> 
      [from: start_date, until: end_date] 
      |> Interval.new()
      |> Enum.to_list()
  end
```

---

Also note, that Elixir guidelines enforce to start the pipe *with a raw value* and *always use parentheses* in calls to functions.

---

According to the scoping issue in your initial question, since there is no *assignment to variable* in Elixir, as well as there are *no variables at all*, the compiler cannot have Schrödinger local `date_list`. Remember: `date_list = ...` is not an assignment, it’s **rebinding**.

Comment: That is an interesting observation about `Kernel.length/1.`  For some reason I had it in my mind that the length of the list would be cached somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

You are assigning internal variables inside the "case" statement. Assign the variable externally like this:

```
date_list = case length(clicks) do
    0 ->
      []
    1 ->
      start_date
    _ ->
      Interval.new(from: start_date, until: end_date) |> Enum.to_list
  end
```